# Swift Animate custom tabcontroller

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I created a custom TabController, when user change tab i animate path from old tab to new. Problem is that stroke is not animated, can u explain, how animate stroke too ?

```
private func drawCurve() {
    let fillColor: UIColor = .white
    let strokeColor: UIColor = Colors.borderTabbarGrayColor
    tabWidth = self.bounds.width / CGFloat(self.items!.count)
    let bezPath = drawPathBorder(for: index) //drawPath(for: index)
    
    bezPath.close()
    fillColor.setFill()
    bezPath.fill()
    bezPath.lineWidth = 1
    strokeColor.setStroke()
    bezPath.stroke()
    
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.fillRule = .evenOdd
    mask.path = bezPath.cgPath
    
    if (self.animated) {
        let bezAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        let bezPathFrom = drawPathBorder(for: previousIndex) //drawPath(for: previousIndex)
        
        bezAnimation.toValue = bezPath.cgPath
        bezAnimation.fromValue = bezPathFrom.cgPath
        bezAnimation.duration = 3.3
        bezAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
        mask.add(bezAnimation, forKey: nil)
    }
    self.layer.mask = mask

}
```

[image]